# Reading FORTRAN-written double precision variables in R

Tags: r, fortran, double

I have a file containing double precisions written from a FORTRAN code in the format of `x.yyyyD+zz`. When using read.csv in R, R does not seem to recognize those as floating point values. I'm new to R; what's the trick here?

Comment: I thought I tried that yesterday and it didn't work. But maybe I did something else wrong then because now it seems to be working... Thanks! Should've tried that again...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `sed` or your favourite text editor to change the `D`s to `E`s, I expect `R` will happily read the numbers after you do that.