# How to sort datafiles with some numbers of Fortran-style D+01?

Tags: bash, sed, fortran, converters, dataformat

I have several Fortran datafiles that contain numbers in a format like this:

```
-0.53D+02
```

I want to combine these with simple floating point data like

```
-0.53
```

and then sort them, like with Unix `sort`.

Unfortunately `sort` can't recognize this format, so I am looking for a simple converter, but couldn't find anything online. I thought about a Fortran script and converting it from `double precision` to `float`, but I am not quite sure about the number of digits and this is always a bit tedious with Fortran.

So does anyone know a script that can do this, a sorting program that can read that format or maybe even just a short `sed` command that might help? I am not that good with sed, so it would cost me quite a while to figure out how...

Comment: Change all D to E by a sed one-liner? Otherwise the correct output Fortran format is very simple, not tedious at all, just `'(f8.3)'` or similar.

Comment: I don't feel this is a duplicate question as it has the additional aspect that `sort` still does not correctly sort the file even when the Ds are changed to Es as in the answer to the other, quoted question.

Comment: I am inclined to agree with reopening and editing the title to "How to sort...", but I don't want to start an edit war, because my reopen vote would open that instantly.

Comment: I am very sad you renamed it, because I actually really want to change the data file and not JUST sort it. There was a good reason to ask the question the way I did.

Comment: You are free to roll back my change.  Of course, with the answer given you can use the `sed` command to give you the changed file without piping it through to `sort`.  [That said, ignoring the title, the question does have the suggestion that sorting is the ultimate goal.]

Comment: @quarky The renaming is mainly for the question not to be a duplicate of the linked one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29962999/reading-fortran-written-double-precision-variables-in-r?lq=1 Maybe how to convert and sort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use this:

```
sed 's/D/E/g' YourNumbersFile | sort -g
```

The `sed` command changes all `D`s to `E`s - read it like this... *"substitute all Ds with Es, globally"*.

The`sort` command needs the `-g` option to sort *general numerical numbers*.

If your `sort` doesn't accept the `-g` switch, I guess another option might be to use this `awk` to reformat your numbers:

```
awk '{sub(/D/,"e");printf "%8.3f\n", $1}' YourNumbersFile | sort -n
```

Comment: This at least solves the sorting problem. Thanks. Good to know that sort can handle E, but not D.

Comment: @rici Thanks for the input. I have suggested a work-around if that is the case.